# Vertically center layer within the user's viewable area on a long page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to vertically center a div in the viewable area on a very long page. The true vertical center of the page is well above the user's viewable area in this case.

I've added the scrollTop() length of the link the users clicks on to the formula which helps, but still places the div above the center of the viewable area.

Code excerpt:

```
$('.' + layer).css({
    display:'block',
    left:( $(window).width() - $('.' + layer).width() )/2,
    top:( $(this).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - $('.' + layer).height() )/2 -20,
    position:'absolute'
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Center DIV contents to viewport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297919/center-div-contents-to-viewport)

Comment: It seems a bit different...going to look over the solution a bit more and see if any of it is transferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need CSS solution?

If your DIV's height = H, css will be:

```
div{ position:fixed; left:0; top:50%; margin-top:(-0.5 * H) }
```